# To which folder does Chocolatey download the packages before installing them?

Tags: chocolatey

I've looked into `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib`.

Each package I've installed has its own folder and some content like this:

```
C:.
|   notepadplusplus.nupkg
|
\---tools
        chocolateyInstall.ps1
```

But there are no files like *notepadplusplus.msi* or *notepadplusplus.zip*.

Does Chocolately remove the package itself after the installation to save harddisk space?

Is there no local cache somewhere?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The local cache defaults to the TEMP folder located at:

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey
```

The cache can also be controlled through the config value `cacheLocation`, which can be set to a different location, which is useful when the TEMP directory is not allowed for downloads.